# Turning (redstone) engines

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have several machines next to each other with wooden pipe outputs at the back of those machines continuing down with other pipes. But when i place the engines to power the wooden pipes they turn to each other after placing the first one. I can place the 1st, 3th, 5th, etc tile but not in between. Is there any way to turn (redstone) engines or someway to place them so the face the proper direction? Or is it impossible to place several wooden pipes with engines next to each other?

Comment: I don't remember with redstone engines, but most need a wrench of some kind to change orientation.

Comment: @Kendra I tried that with my upgraded electrical wrench without success.

Comment: Depending on the mods you're running, it might need a different one. I honestly don't remember what turns the redstone ones, though.

Comment: You could always put an extra space between them. That will do it. It will take extra space, though.

Comment: Redstone engines should work with most wrenches. But regardless there can't be too many wrenches for you to try, look up wrench in NEI and use process of elimination. I use the wrench that uses refined Iron in a squarish Y pattern for my redstone engines, always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper wrench/tool from the same mod as the object you want to interact with. In your case the buildcraft wrench since a redstone engine comes with buildcraft.

There are multiple types of wrenches and tools to interact with objects. Basically each mod pack comes with its own "tool" some may work together like the build craft wrench works on forestry items. This makes things a bit complicated since you have so many tools for all the different mods but as of now there is no combined multitool for all/most mods yet.